# How to copy files using Net::SSH in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ssh, scp, net-ssh

So far as I can tell I need to use both Net::SCP and Net::SSH if I want to copy a file to a remote host and then manipulate it from the command line.

It would be nice to set up one SSH session, do the copy and then use the same connection to unpack the file and install them.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Net::SCP allows you to easily grab a Net::SCP reference from an existing Net::SSH session:

```
require "net/ssh"
require "net/scp"
Net::SSH.start("remote.host", "username", :password => "passwd") do |ssh|
  ssh.scp.upload("/local/path", "/remote/path")
  ssh.exec("...insert commands...")
end
```

Read more here: http://net-ssh.github.io/net-scp/classes/Net/SCP.html

Comment: Can I also delete the file from the remote server after it is downloaded?

Comment: Using the SSH session this should be possible. Simply execute the 'rm' command : 'rm /path/to/file'

Comment: Won't this create the problem of deleting the file before it was even downloaded? Race condition.

Comment: I'm not sure. You could always wait until the file has finished downloading before deleting it

Comment: In your code how would you know that the file is uploaded/downloaded? Is there something like `channel.on_download_complete`. PS I couldn't find it. I was doing 3 ssh sessions to manipulate file, download file and then delete the file.

Comment: I could do this
```ssh.scp.download!("/remote/path", "/local/path")
ssh.exec("some command")```
But this blocks the flow. I had multiple files to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Net::SFTP? Along with that and Tempfile, I am currently using it in a project to copy from local to remote. You can also do simple file modifications. If you were so inclined, you could use Stream.IO to edit the file even more.

https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp

http://net-ssh.github.io/net-sftp/